# What happens when you send a Adobe air application to a computer without adobe air installed?

Tags: air, launching-application

If I have a app.air installer and I send it to a computer via email in which that computer doesn't have adobe air installed, presumably the OS wont recognize the .air extension. So what are my possibilities of action besides telling the client to install Adobe Air first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the computer doesn't recognize the file extension so it cannot open it.